# Flutter - Change style of bottom navbar while scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

In Flutter, I want the bottom nav bar to change to a different style when the page is scrolled, and to return to its original state when it is stopped. I have two designs, these are;

[image]

[image]

When scrolled, the first design should be seen.

I created a solution, but this was not enough in terms of performance, can anyone with a better solution help?
These are my codes.

```
  class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool isHidden = false;
  double offSet = 0;
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      double temp = scrollController.offset;

      if ((temp - offSet).abs() < 10) {
        setState(() {
          isHidden = false;
          offSet = scrollController.offset;

        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          isHidden = true;
          offSet = scrollController.offset;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: isHidden ? BottomNavBar1() : BottomNavBar2(),
      body: ListView(
        controller: scrollController,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```